# Squares in a triangular lattice

Tags: geometry

It is not difficult to show that the points of an integer lattice do not span any equilateral triangles (for example, [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105330/equilateral-triangle-with-integer-coordinates)).

Is it also true that the points of a triangular lattice do not span any squares?

That is, a lattice that is composed of the vertices of a [tiling of equilateral triangles](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/eps-gif/TriangularGrid_700.gif), or equivalently:
$\left\{a\cdot (1,0) + b\cdot (1/2, \sqrt{3}/2) \ \mid \mbox{ for any } a,b\in{\mathbb Z} \right\}$.

Thanks,

Adam

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With $\rho=\frac{1+i\sqrt 3}2$, we have $\rho\notin\mathbb Q[i]$ and $i\notin\mathbb Q[\rho]$