# Almost equilateral triangles on lattice

Tags: diophantine-equations, triangles

- It is impossible to build equilateral triangle with all vertices on lattice 
  (just consider rotation of any lattice point around the origin by $60^{\circ}$).
- Denote *defect* of triangle $\triangle ABC$ as
  $$d_{\triangle ABC} = d_A + d_B + d_C,$$
  where *defect* of the vertex $A$ is 
  $$d_{A}= |AB|^2 - |AC|^2.$$
- The smallest defect of the triangle on lattice is $2$.

   Let call such triangles "almost equilateral triangles on lattice" (AETL).

   Possible combinations of side lengths of AETLs are:
  $(\sqrt{n}, \sqrt{n}, \sqrt{n+1})$ and 
  $(\sqrt{n-1}, \sqrt{n}, \sqrt{n})$,
  where $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

[image: Triangles]

- I see only $2$ (infinite) sets of such triangles:

  the set $S_1$: 
  \begin{array}{|c|c|}
  \hline
  side \; lengths & example\; of\; triangle \; vertices\; \\
  \hline
  \sqrt{2k^2-1}, \sqrt{2k^2-1}, k\sqrt{2} & (0,0) \; (a,b) \; (b,a) \\
  \hline
  1,1,\sqrt{2} & (0,0)\; (1,0)\; (0,1) \\
  \sqrt{17},\sqrt{17},3\sqrt{2} & (0,0)\; (4,1)\; (1,4) \\
  \sqrt{241},\sqrt{241},11\sqrt{2} & (0,0)\; (15,4)\; (4,15) \\
  \sqrt{3361},\sqrt{3361},41\sqrt{2} & (0,0)\; (56,15)\; (15,56) \\
  \sqrt{46817},\sqrt{46817},153\sqrt{2} & (0,0)\; (209,56)\; (56,209) \\
  \cdots & \cdots \\
  \hline
  \end{array}
  where $k_{j+1}=4k_j-k_{j-1}$; ($a_{j+1},b_{j+1} -$ similar way);

   the set $S_2$:
  \begin{array}{|c|c|}
  \hline
  side \; lengths & example\; of\; triangle \; vertices\; \\
  \hline
  k,\sqrt{k^2+1}, \sqrt{k^2+1} & (0,0) \; (a,b) \; (a,-b) \\
  \hline
  2,\sqrt{5},\sqrt{5} & (0,0)\; (2,1)\; (2,-1) \\
  8,\sqrt{65},\sqrt{65} & (0,0)\; (7,4)\; (7,-4) \\
  30,\sqrt{901},\sqrt{901} & (0,0) (26,15) (26,-15) \\
  112,\sqrt{12545},\sqrt{12545} & (0,0) (97,56) (97,-56) \\
  418,\sqrt{174725},\sqrt{174725} & (0,0) (362,209) (362,-209) \\
  \cdots & \cdots \\
  \hline
  \end{array}
  where $k_{j+1}=4k_j-k_{j-1}$; ($a_{j+1},b_{j+1} -$ similar way).

**Question:** is there almost equilateral triangle on lattice with sides which are not included to described sets?

---

My suggested approach: move one of the vertices to the origin; then draw the circle with radius $\sqrt{n}$, and consider distances between lattice points of the circle. But I'm not sure that other solutions exist at all.

Comment: I think you want the impossibility of _equilateral_  triangles, not _right_ triangles ... See  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105330/equilateral-triangle-whose-vertices-are-lattice-points

Comment: @EthanBolker: thank you, will fix immediately.

Answer (score 4):

This is related to [Pell's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation) $x^2-3y^2=1$ and the related $x^2-3y^2=-1$.  If you split an equilateral triangle in half you get a $1-\sqrt 3-2$ right triangle so you need to approximate $\sqrt 3$ by a rational.  These are known to form families due to the Fermat-Brahmagupta identity giving a recurrence for larger solutions.