# Can a regular $n$-simplex have vertices in $\mathbb Z^n$ for $n > 1$?

Tags: geometry, triangles, integer-lattices, simplex, polytopes

Trivially, a regular $0$-simplex (point) and $1$-simplex (line segment) can have integer vertices in $0$ and $1$ dimensional Euclidean space respectively. On the other hand, a regular $2$-simplex (equilateral triangle) [cannot have vertices in $\mathbb Z^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/105387/121988).

Is it true more generally that an $n$-simplex cannot have vertices in $\mathbb Z^n$ for $n > 1$? Is there an easy way to see this?

#### Edit:

Eugen J. Ionascu [provides an example](http://ejionascu.ro/talks/troy2011.pdf) of a regular tetrahedron with vertices in $\mathbb Z^3$:
$(0,0,4),(7,0,3),(3,5,0),(4,5,7)$

Do such regular $n$-simplices exist for all $n \neq 2$?

Comment: What about $(0,0,0),(1,1,0),(1,0,1),(0,1,1)$?

Comment: See one of the answers in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/38724/coordinates-of-vertices-of-regular-simplex. The statement is that it's possible iff n+1 is the sum of one, two, four or eight odd squares!

Comment: It looks like the question is answered [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/278776) on MathOverflow.